# How to snap an object over another object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Hi I'm using Adobe Illustrator can someone please help me, I'm trying to snap an object to the edge of another object. But instead its snapping a few pixels away. I also tried using "Snap to Point" but no use.[image: this is what happening] The white object has to place along with the edge of beneath object.But snaps away.

Even at max zoom(6400%) I can't place the object.[image: this is what it should be] In second image the blue line is where I am trying to place white object.

Is there anything to do with preferences setting. If so please help me.

> I have also looked
>   [How to rotate and snap an object into a desired position? [Illustrator]](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42504/how-to-rotate-and-snap-an-object-into-a-desired-position-illustrator)
>   but its not helping me out

Comment: Expand the extrude first.

Answer (score 1):

When snapping an object to another I find that using 'Smart Guides' is the easiest way.
This feature highlights possible ways that the object you are moving might align with or snap to other objects on your page. It does this by showing pink lines between the objects.
[image: Smart Guides turned on]

Turn on Smart Guides by pressing Control/Cmd + U or in 'View' menu select 'Smart Guides'

In your example, try dragging the white shape by grabbing its top left corner and snapping to the inner corner of the yellow shape.

If you need to snap a vertex of one object to a non-horizontal/vertical edge of another object, you may find that it will not snap where you expect. In this situation, press Control/Cmd when dragging. This will force Smart Guides to align/snap from the vertex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you have forgotten to disable Snap to grid or to activate snapping to point. Snap to point is the way to go, when everything is not arranged along the predefined rectangular grid.

If you drag the  object  keeping the mouse cursor on some point of  its outline curve, just that point will snap to an anchor point of another object (=a node in objects outline curve). The cursor changes it's color, if there is a valid anchor point near enough.

If there is no anchor point in the right place, you should insert one to the object outline, which is wanted to be reached exactly.

The max snapping distance can be given in preferences on subpage Selection & Anchor display. The distance limit is given as screen pixels.

Comment: Sometimes one needs to hold ctrl down for the snapping to recognize the point if its in another layer. Also effects are not objects for the snap so they need to be expanded first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the two objects (The face of the B, not the extrude) and the highlight can just simply be lined up with the `Align` Tab.

- Using the White Arrow, click the highlight.
- Hold shift, click the face of the B
- Use the Black Arrow and click the face of the B again (it should get a thicker selection around it, this means it is the object that everything will be aligned to)
- In the Align Tab, make sure that `Align To` is set to `Selection`. (If you cannot see this, click `Show Options` in the tab).
- Click `Align Horizontal Right`
- Click `Align Vertical Top`

I stopped trying to do much alignment by hand a long time ago. I try to use the `Align` tab as much as I can now. It won’t always be applicable, but in this case it will work.